# How can I add styles to a form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some forms and I would like to add classes to the elements. Here is an example:

```
<form ... id="test1"> </form>
<form ... id="test2"> </form>
```

I found the following but I don't understand the syntax of the first few lines

```
(function ($) {

    $.widget("ui.format", {

        _init: function () {

            var self = this; //the plugin object
            var o = self.options; //user options

            //get all form elements
            var form = self.element; //the form that reformed was called on
            var fieldsets = form.find('fieldset');
            var legends = form.find('legend');
            var text_inputs = form.find('input[type="text"] , input[type="password"] , textarea');
            var checkboxes = form.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            var radios = form.find('input[type="radio"]');
            var buttons = form.find('input[type="reset"] , input[type="submit"], button');

            //add appropraite styles to form elements
            form.addClass('ui-widget');
            fieldsets.addClass('ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
            legends.addClass('ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');
            text_inputs.addClass('ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');




 }); //end plugin

})(jQuery);
```

In particular I don't understand this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.format", {
        _init: function () {
```

and the last line:

```
})(jQuery);
```

Can someone explain to me what it means and step me through just these three lines.

For example:

- What does the _init mean
- Can I use mixed case for "ui.format" and is this the name of the function?
- What's the .widget mean, how could I apply this code to my form? I assume I would need to call it somehow from inside my document ready and then attach it to a particular form id.
- Also what happens if I apply this to my form and then later on apply it again. Will it add the same classes twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(function ($) {` starts off a pattern that is commonly used with jQuery plugins (and many other JavaScript functions). The entire pattern is:

```
(function ($) { //declare an anonymous function that accepts a parameter called '$'
    //your code goes here
}(jQuery)); //Close the anonymous function and pass it the jQuery object
```

Wrapping the whole thing in parentheses makes it execute as soon as it loads (i.e., before the DOM is ready).

The `$.widget("ui.format", {` begins to extend the [jQuery widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory) passing in 'ui.format' as the "namespace.widgetname" and then the `{` starts the object to pass in.

"what does the _init mean": `_init: function() {` is a function called "_init" that is being defined in the object passed in to the widget factory.

"can I use mixed case for "ui.format"": No, as it's the namespaced widget that is being modified and JavaScript is case-sensitive.

As far as applying this to your code, I haven't seen this plugin before so I'll have to refer you to the documentation on the site where you got it.

In general, you apply jQuery widgets by passing a selector to the jQuery object and calling the widget (i.e., `$('form#test1').ui.widget();`).

You can also add classes with the `.addClass()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form#test1').addClass('yourClassHere');
    $('form#test1').addClass('yourNextClassHere');
    //or just chain them together like so...
    $('form#test1').addClass('classOne').addClass('classTwo').addClass('classThree');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the script looks like:

```
(function($) {
  $.widget("ui.format", {
    _init: function() {
      ...
      ...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The first line (coupled with the last) just means that upon parsing through the script it will actually run it right away. ie: it will run as soon as it's loaded.

Second line is just call the jquery plugin widget and passing in two parameters:

one is the string "ui.format"
  two is an javascript object, where _init is defined as a function.

Most likely, somewhere in the plugin code, _init will be called like _init().

Comment: Thanks - So how would I attach this to a form?